# Prove an equation about Frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-norms

The problem:

Show that if $\textbf{0} \neq \textbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $E \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, then

$$\Big\lVert E(I - \frac{\textbf{v}\textbf{v}^{T}}{\textbf{v}^{T}\textbf{v}})\Big\rVert_{F}^{2} = \|E\|_{F}^{2} - \frac{\|E \textbf{v}\|_{2}^{2}}{\textbf{v}^{T}\textbf{v}}$$

What I have tried:

LHS = $\Big\|E - E\frac{\textbf{v}\textbf{v}^{T}}{\textbf{v}^{T}\textbf{v}}\Big\|_{F}^{2}$

and I want to expand it using $ \|A\|_{F}^{2} = \mathrm{tr}(AA^{T})$.

But it seems too complicated, am I on the right track? Or could there be any more efficient ways?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You should roll up your sleeves and go on with the expansion.

Comment: This is a Pythagoras identity. Essentially you have to show that the vector-orthogonal projection on the left is still an orthogonal projection for the matrix-Euclidean scalar product that gives the Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that hard, maybe safe yourself some notation first. Set $P:=vv^T/v^Tv$, then
$$
\|E-EP\|_F^2 
= 
\mathrm{tr}[(E-EP)(E-EP)^T]
=
\mathrm{tr}(EE^T-EP^TE^T-EPE^T+EPP^TE^T).
$$
Now as already pointed out, $P$ is an orthogonal projection, that is, $P^T=P$ and $P^2=PP^T=P$. Using it above gives
$$
\begin{split}
\|E-EP\|_F^2 &= \mathrm{tr}(EE^T-EPE^T-EPE^T+EPE^T)\\ 
&= \mathrm{tr}(EE^T-EPE^T)
= \mathrm{tr}[EE^T-EP(EP)^T]\\
&= \mathrm{tr}(EE^T)-\mathrm{tr}[EP(EP)^T] =\|E\|_F^2 - \|EP\|_F^2
\end{split}
$$
Finally,
$$
\begin{split}
\|EP\|_F^2&=\mathrm{tr}[(EP)^TEP]=\mathrm{tr}(P^TE^TEP)\\
&=\mathrm{tr}(vv^TE^TEvv^T)/(v^Tv)^2=\frac{v^TE^TEv\cdot v^Tv}{(v^Tv)^2} = \frac{\|Ev\|_2^2}{v^Tv}.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: One could also directly go $tr(EPE^T)=\frac{tr(Evv^TE^T}{v^Tv}=\frac{\|Ev\|_F^2}{v^Tv}$. But having $\|E(1-P)\|_F^2+\|EP\|_F^2=\|E\|_F^2$ established as Pythagoras formula adds didactic value.